# speechSynthesis API example gives error

Tags: javascript, html, api, speech-synthesis

The example given on [Web Speech API Specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#dfn-ttscancel)

```
    speechSynthesis.speak(SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World'));
```

gives the following error on chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: DOM object constructor cannot be called as a
>   function.

Can anyone help here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a type in the specifications and you are expected to use the `new` keyword with the `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` object.  Try this:

```
speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World'));
```

Comment: Also, bear in mind it must be triggered by a user event (e.g. button press).

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code and [a jsbin as well](http://jsbin.com/gosaqihi/9/edit?js,console) to help demonstrate how to use the APIs together:

```
var utterance = new window.SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
utterance.lang = 'ja-JP'; //translates on the fly - soooo awesome (japanese is the funniest)
utterance.volume = 1.0;
utterance.rate = 1.0;
utterance.pitch = 1.0;
utterance.voice = 'Hysterical'; // this seems to do nothing
utterance.text = "Facebook news feeds are full of garbage";

//Speak the phrase
window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);

window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function () {
  var speechSynthesisVoices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  var accents = _(speechSynthesisVoices).pluck('lang');
  var voices = _(speechSynthesisVoices).pluck('voiceURI');
  var names = _(speechSynthesisVoices).pluck('name');
  console.log('names', names);
  console.log('accents', _.uniq(accents));
  console.log('voices', voices);
};
```