# SpeechSynthesisUtterance not working in mobile broswer

Tags: mobile, browser, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, webspeech-api

I am using SpeechSynthesisUtterance in my mobile website. This code is okay when I use it in my desktop version website. But I found that the function is not working in mobile browser in document.ready as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var text_tts="say something";
 speakText(text_tts);
    });
function speakText(text_tts){
var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
u.text = text_tts;
u.lang = 'en-US';
u.rate = 1;
u.onend = function(event) { console.log('Finished in ' + event.elapsedTime + ' seconds.'); }
speechSynthesis.speak(u);
```

}

But when I use "click" event, it works:

```
$("body").on("click",".button",function(){
         var tmp_body_text="say something";
                   var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
                   u.text = tmp_body_text;
                   u.lang = 'en-US';
                   u.rate = 1;
                   //u.onend = function(event) { console.log('Finished in ' + event.elapsedTime + ' seconds.'); }
                   speechSynthesis.speak(u);
                   });
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen several mentions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292625/speechsynthesis-api-example-gives-error#comment-28435322), for example) that `speak` only works when called from a user interaction, such as a click. From what I have seen, that seems to be the case for Safari on iOS, and that appears to be what you are describing in your question.

I have not actually found any kind of documentation that confirms this behavior, and would appreciate any references anyone can provide.

Comment: I have run into the same situation, on iOS user has to have initiated it... not sure what the idea is behind that or how to get around it. :(