# Web Speech API text-to-speech not working on mobile

Tags: android, google-chrome, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

The below works on Desktop Chrome/Safari/Firefox, but not on mobile.

Even though on Chrome mobile I have 1) `SpeechRecognition` working perfectly; 2) `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` loads correctly, I can check all the attributes, load voices (remote debugging via DevTools) - just the phone wouldn't speak (iPhone Safari and Android Chrome tested).

Also, when I try this [demo](https://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/wGzuJ) on mobile, it says my browser supports speech synthesis, I can select from the voices available, but the browser won't speak.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

```
<script>
    var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    u.text = "hello world";
    speechSynthesis.speak(u);
</script>
```

Comment: Restarting the phone solved it for me. Wouldn't have thought...

Comment: For others: Do turn on your loudspeakers. Happened to me...

Answer (score 2):

Android Chrome :

I opened my " so nice, wonderful and fantastic Html page with java script " and I discovered nothing works on my mobile phone... (Android)

1.) I googled and found https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006983?hl=en

Text-to-speech output
To specify text-to-speech settings for your device:
Open your device's Settings app .
Select Accessibility, then Text-to-speech output.
Choose your preferred engine, language, speech rate, and pitch.
Note: The default text-to-speech engine choices vary by device. Options can include Google's Text-to-speech engine, the device manufacturer's engine, and any third-party text-to-speech engines that you've downloaded from the Google Play Store.
Optional: To hear a short demonstration of speech synthesis, press Play.
Optional: To install voice data for another language, select Settings ,  then Install voice data. Choose the language that you want to install.

Note : (Select Accessibility, then Text-to-speech output.)

I activated "touch to hear", as my options were filled with whatever, but not the above mentioned. The "TalkBack" instead was a little too heavy, so I left it "unused /unselected " ...

2.) speechSynthesis.resume() and speechSynthesis.pause(); do not work, no other solution for now, than excluding them if mobile browser / touch device is detected.

Comment: Hopefully we can get the .pause() and .resume() functions to work again, this is what breaks the 15 second workaround currently.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it may be related to: [SpeechSynthesisUtterance not working in mobile broswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806399/speechsynthesisutterance-not-working-in-mobile-broswer?rq=3). It seems that, on mobile browsers, the speech must be initiated by a user interaction at least once, in order to be subsequently initiated programmatically from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In a related problem, the following code speaks in Chrome Android, but the event listener doesn't seem to be calling the NextWord function while it works fine on Chrome and Safari on macOS:

```
speechTextString = "Hello World"
speechText = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance( speechTextString );
    speechText.onboundary = function (event)  {
    if ( event.name == "word" ) { NextWord( event.charIndex ) }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding window in front of speechSynthesis?
The code is window.speechSynthesis.speak(u) .

Answer (score 0):

I have filed, when I wrote (2020), the entire problem with Chromium and Android. Android developers filed the Bug and gave a solution.

So today it is working , BUT !!!!

In chromium the language syntax of a whatever speaker is :

en_UK, speakername

In many Android devices ( the ones I tested, so just many ) it becomes :

en-UK, speakername

This means that a predefined speaker in a web page loaded Android, will never match already the language code, speaker, choosen and defined by a Chrome, Firefox , etc browser....

The workaround is to :

languageSpeaker = 'en-UK, speakername'; <-- stringify it !!!

then split by (',') :

var langPairs = languageSpeaker.split(',');

then :

var language = langPairs[0][0] + langPairs[0][1];

var dialect  = langPairs[0][3] + langPairs[0][4];

var speaker = langPairs[1];

With this information you are able to search recursively

1.) is language supported ?
2.) is language and dialect supported ?
3.) is language and dialect and speaker supported ?

Avoid going by the speaker first as the speaker called " Daniel ", will answer positively both for French as for English.